# How to zip files on folder that have specific file type as xlsx?

Tags: c#, .net

I work on c# app doing compress files using zip file I face Issue I cannot control Type of file compress 
as xlsx,jpg ,etc ...

so I need to add extension type(File Type) for files compress inside source folder as optional parameter to determine which files will be zip

so How to add optional parameter extension type as xlsx to function Zip .

**Expected Result :**

suppose I have folder name source have 3 files A.xlsx,B.xlsx ,c.jpg .

and I call function Zip(source folder, destination Folder,optional xlsx)

then it will compress files A.xlsx,B.xlsx only because I pass extension xlsx

so I need to add new parameter to function zip below that have extension type as xlsx or jpg as optional

```
public void Zip(string source, string destination)
        {
            using (Ionic.Zip.ZipFile zip = new Ionic.Zip. ZipFile
            {
                CompressionLevel = CompressionLevel.BestCompression
            })
            {
                var files = Directory.GetFiles(source, "*",
                    SearchOption.AllDirectories).
                    Where(f => Path.GetExtension(f).
                        ToLowerInvariant() != ".zip").ToArray();

                foreach (var f in files)
                {
                    zip.AddFile(f, GetCleanFolderName(source, f));
                }

                var destinationFilename = destination;

                if (Directory.Exists(destination) && !destination.EndsWith(".zip"))
                {
                    destinationFilename += $"\\{new DirectoryInfo(source).Name}-{DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-ffffff}.zip";
                }

                zip.Save(destinationFilename);
            }
        }

        private string GetCleanFolderName(string source, string filepath)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filepath))
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

            var result = filepath.Substring(source.Length);

            if (result.StartsWith("\\"))
            {
                result = result.Substring(1);
            }

            result = result.Substring(0, result.Length - new FileInfo(filepath).Name.Length);

            return result;
        }
```

updated post :

I can compress files based on extension type excel xlsx

by doing that

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(source, "*",
                    SearchOption.AllDirectories).
                    Where(f => Path.GetExtension(f).
                        ToLowerInvariant() == ".xlsx").ToArray();
```

so how to pass extension type xlsx as parameter optional .

Comment: check out [named-and-optional-arguments#optional-arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments#optional-arguments)

Comment: and what about extension type .xlsx

Comment: How to determince extension type of file xlsx

Comment: I make updated post

Comment: where answer I see answer post then deleted why

Comment: can you please repost answer it deleted

Answer (score 0):

Check out the function, this might help you. This function supports filtering multiple extensions also check usage as shown below. Check the link for usage of [Params Keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params#example)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sourceDirectory = "";

        //Usage of this function
        //Wrap this call in try catch to handle access denied exception for files if required
        //When want to filter out files with extension ".txt" and ".xlsx"
        GetFilteredFilesFromDirectory(sourceDirectory, SearchOption.AllDirectories, ".txt", ".xlsx");


        //In case you dont want to filter anything
        GetFilteredFilesFromDirectory(sourceDirectory, SearchOption.AllDirectories);


        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// FIlter the files based on extensions
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">Source Directory</param>
    /// <param name="searchOption">SearchOption<see cref="SearchOption"/></param>
    /// <param name="includeOnlyExtensions">File Extension to inlcude e.g. ".txt",".xlsx"</param>
    /// <returns>Return filtered files</returns>
    static IEnumerable<string> GetFilteredFilesFromDirectory(string source, SearchOption searchOption, params string[] includeOnlyExtensions)
    {
        var query = Directory.GetFiles(source, "*", searchOption);
        if (includeOnlyExtensions.Any())
            return query.Where(x => includeOnlyExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(x)));
        else
            return query;
    }
}
```

You can use this function to get filter extension and make changes to zip function as follows

```
    public void Zip(string source, string destination,params string[] includeExtensions)
    {            
       ...your code 

       var files = GetFilteredFilesFromDirectory(sourceDirectory, SearchOption.AllDirectories, includeExtensions);

      ... your code
    }
```

Comment: I need to use optional on zip function it self you already do on getfiltering function but i need on zip function it self

Comment: if i use zip function it will be now as following : Zip(string source, string destination,'xlsx') are this correct or not

Comment: Zip(string source, string destination,'.xlsx') like this. Note the "." in extension. Check usage in post